# Extracting lines containing pattern + next line

Tags: linux, text-processing, bioinformatics

I have two files: one containing a list of IDs (file A) and other containing a list of IDs plus their corresponding text -which is always on the next line- (file B).

File A:

```
>161@1983
>947@2009
>59@2002
>5933@2005
```

File B:

```
>161@1983
text
>8899@2007
more text
>6000@2017
more and more text
>5933@2005
idk
>31@2004
you get the idea
etc...
```

How can I extract only the IDs + their corresponding text from file B that match the IDs from file A?

Expected output:

```
>161@1983
text
>5933@2005
idk
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep, FreeBSD grep:

```
grep -A1 -Ff fileA fileB
```

Comment: Tried it on my files and didn't work.. Gives me a blank output. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Manuel does fileA contains id the same string as id in fileB? `-F` causes the id line in fileA matches the id line in fileB, if it's substring, or pattern, then it doesn't match

Comment: FileA's and B's IDs are exact same strings. Not substrings nor patterns.

Comment: @Manuel So checking if you have trailing whitespaces? I tested with your input and it give me desired output. Also make sure `fileA` is the one contains list of ids, and the `fileA fileB` order in command line is a must.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried with the example I provided and it worked. Weird. Already checked for whitespaces and everything is ok. FileA contains 535 IDs and fileB contains 3736 IDs + 3736 lines of text, one after each ID. Can size be an issue when using your command?

Comment: @Manuel No, maybe you should check newline of your files. Do they copy from Windows machine?

Comment: @Manuel use tool like `dos2unix` or you can search the site for related problem

Comment: Yes! FileA comes from a Windows machine. Copied the contents of fileA to a new file and it worked. Many thanks @cuonglm